# Prims Algorithm and Kruskal Algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

- Can the Prims and Kruskal algorithms yield the same value?
- Can every graph can use Prims and Kruskal algorithms?

Comment: Of course they can since the optimial is only value.

Comment: Kruskal is pretty easy to implement

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Prims and Kruskal algorithms will both yield the same minimum total weight of the minimum spanning tree (MST), but may provide different, optimal MST's.

Every undirected graph can use Prims and Kruskal, but there are slight differences in the algorithms that sometimes make Prims (dense graphs) or Kruskal (sparse graph) the better choice.

See this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195872/kruskal-vs-prim) for more details of the differences.

Comment: They don't necessarily yield the same answer. We use them to find a minimum spanning tree of a graph, and since a graph may have multiple minimum spanning trees, these may differ.

Comment: Good point, I edited it for clarity. I was thinking of the total weight of the tree, which should be the same.